# How can i adjust the height and width of pagination buttons in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]

how can i resize this highlighted buttons all of them?

i want to make it smaller in size.

Comment: ref this article https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51347/editing-pagination-button-size @Ashish Shukla

Comment: @SandeshMankar i dont want the pagination number to be removed i want to resize the button present i.e page number values 1  2  3  this buttons i want to resize.

Comment: Add this style in your code <style> .pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span{line-height:0.428571;}</style> and you can get your output.

Comment: @Jinesh i tried it i place this <style> .pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span{line-height:0.428571;}</style>  piece of code in my Bootstrap modal code where i am using the jquery datatable but no changes .

Answer (score 1):

[image: inspect element to find css class]

i just done it by inspecting the button element from firefox browser.. and just overwrite that particular property with "!important" keyword in style tag. i attached the sample image.

```
<style>
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button
    {
        min-width: 0.2em; !important
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: i did it but not reflecting on UI

Comment: https://codepen.io/pradeepBhati/pen/xxGwdxG
i just did it here just change the value of padding..
like this you can modify the other property also.

Comment: @PradeepBhati note that you should terminate after ```!important``` not before.